# Language Bar change language in c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, globalization

**TL;DR**: Trying to solve the issue that `InputLanguage` changes the input layout but does not update the Language Bar display.

---

I am writing a custom plugin for Trados Studio. Part of this is interfacing with languages both in the app itself and in Word, as in this question: [List of all available languages for Windows .NET framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244656/list-of-all-available-languages-for-windows-net-framework)

The last problem I seem to cannot solve is that in a part of the code I am using `InputLanguage` to set the keyboard input to en-US.

*To clarify, there is a **limited API,** so I have to be really inventive in automating certain aspects. The best workable approach was to use the default shortcuts in the application:*

1. First I change the input language to en-US.
2. Then I send some keys to the application.
3. Then I change the input language back to what it was before.
4. Then I show a form.

Here is the code:

```
//change input language to English
InputLanguage currentLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
InputLanguage newLang = InputLanguage.FromCulture(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
if (newLang == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Upload Project function requires the En-US keyboard installed.", "Missing keyboard", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    return;
}
else
{
    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = newLang;
}

//Save the document
SendKeys.SendWait("^s");

InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = currentLang;

//get url and credentials from a custom input form
string[] psw = UploadData.GetPassword(
    Settings.GetValue("Upload", "Uri", "https://www.scntranslations.org/ws/services"),
    Vars.wsUsername == null ? Settings.GetValue("Upload", "User", "") : Vars.wsUsername,
    Vars.wsPassword == null ? "" : Vars.wsPassword
    );
Application.DoEvents();
```

The manifestation that I have is that the Language Bar changes with a delay to **EN** but by the time the form shows up it should be **HU** yet it stays **EN**.

However if I test it with `Debug.WriteLine(InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName)` then the output is the correct language (in my case "Hungarian").

Even after the form is hidden, the language remains **EN**, yet the keyboard types in Hungarian and the `Debug.WriteLine(InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage.LayoutName)` returns "Hungarian".

I looked at dozens of pages on SO and the web and I tried everything I could think of including `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` and `Application.DoEvents()` and `Sendkeys.Flush()`, but nothing triggers Windows to update the Language Bar, and I could not find any solution to this issue.

The earlier version of this problem as given in this question: [Change keyboard layout from C# code with .NET 4.5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291533/change-keyboard-layout-from-c-sharp-code-with-net-4-5-2)
I have made this work now fully with the above implementation of the `InputLanguage` bar this last hick-up.

---

**Can anybody help in:**

1. giving an explanation for this behavior?
2. suggesting a solution that triggers the update of the Language Bar from C# code?

**UPDATE:** The code now fully works. I implemented the BlockInput WinAPI.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "BlockInput")]
[return: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool BlockInput([System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fBlockIt);
```

And also turning off the Caps Lock using Win API:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

private void TurnOffCapsLock()
{
    if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock)) // Checks Capslock is on
    {
        const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
        const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;
        NativeMethods.keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr)0);
        NativeMethods.keybd_event(0x14, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
        (UIntPtr)0);
    }
}
```

*So what's left really is getting the Language Bar to correctly show the actual current input language.*

I do have the option of sending Alt+Shifts, but I really don't want to do that.

Comment: So when you call `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = newLang;` it changes to `EN` but doesn't change when you try to set it back to to `currentLang`? Must be something to do with the 4 calls to `SendWait`, why don't you try adding a few waits in and see if the language changes then?

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy - No, the input language does change, but the _Language Bar_ does not update. The `SendWait` calls all go through and the show forms up. But by the time the for shows up the code already changed back to `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = currentLang;` Also, what "waits" you mean exactly?

Comment: What are trying to do. Is faking input really the solution to your problem?

Comment: How did you conclude that UI Automation would not work?

Comment: When you don't recognise terminology don's web search.

Comment: Only by doing some web search which I am sure you are perfectly capable of.

Comment: Anybody has any idea?